# I can't access the Election Page

Tags: bug, status-completed

The link

```
http://askubuntu.com/election
```

from the Comments Inbox is going to

```
http://askubuntu.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/election
```

[image]

Comment: Reported on twitter too https://twitter.com/thatcoderiguana/status/739968540711616512

Comment: it is working now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are on it, fixing it, see [here](https://twitter.com/Nick_Craver/status/739976957434187776).

It is not only you who want to have a look at it, many questions have been raised in the chats as well about it.

Comment: It is back now.